# CouchDB Exported file won't import back into database

Tags: json, couchdb

So a friend running a script for me fetched all the documents in a couchdb data base to a json file. The file looks something like this.

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"1410","key":"1410","value":{"rev":"1-4057566831"},"doc":{"_id":"bar","_rev":"1-4057566831","name":"jim"}},
{"id":"1411","key":"1411","value":{"rev":"1-2842770487"},"doc":{"_id":"baz","_rev":"1-2842770487","name":"trunky"}}
]}
```

So now I have a 60MB json file, and want to put it back into a locally hosted couchdb database.

```
curl -X POST -d @jsonfile.json 127.0.0.1:5984/db_name/_bulk_docs
```

Doesn't work. it tells me that the file is not json. Even specifying that it's json doesn't work.

So now I have a json file and I can't seem to put it into a database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me `curl -d @data.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/_bulk_docs` on OSX with CouchDB 1.6.0.

Two things might be going on.

`-d` automatically sets the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. [1](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) so you need to include `-H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'`.

Also the `_bulk_docs` specification[2](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html) requires a different structure than a standard reply from a view or `_all_docs`.

```
{
  "docs" : [
    {"_id":"1","name":"calvin"},
    {"_id":"2","name":"hobbes"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Used this: `C:\wamp\www\DataViz>curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: applicat
ion/json' -vX POST --data-binary @DataVizfinal.json http://127.0.0.1:5984/DataViz5` [Got this:](http://pastebin.com/fYe4FeWx)

Comment: I added an example that should clear up a few problems in your command syntax.